# Force all figures but not tables to the end of a document

Tags: tables, endfloat

I wanted to put all my figures at the end of my pdf.

I was advised to use:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists]{endfloat}
```

which worked great. However, my tables are also placed at the end of the document, but I would prefer to keep these in the text.

Is there any way to place the plots at the end of the document, but not the tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the package with the `figuresonly` option:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists,figuresonly]{endfloat}
```

Comment: I got the error: Package endfloat Warning: Unknown option `figuresonly' on input line 95.

Comment: @user1551817 Which version of the package are you using?

Comment: Is this the package version: endfloat.sty    1995/10/11 v2.4i LaTeX2e package puts figures and tables at end

Comment: @user1551817 You are using a really outdated version! (The package was updated in 2011: in my sytem: `2011/12/25 v2.5d LaTeX2e package puts figures and tables at end (jdm)`). Please update the [endfloat package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) and everything will work.